# SQL Array aggregation in Haskell + Squeal

Tags: sql, postgresql, haskell

I'm using an SQL library called **Squeal** in Haskell.

### What's the correct way to aggregate multiple text rows into one array in Squeal library?

Say I got a very simple Schema with just one table containing a column '**keyword**' (of PG text type) + associated types:

```
import           Squeal.PostgreSQL
import qualified GHC.Generics                  as GHC
import qualified Generics.SOP                  as SOP

type Constraints = '["pk_keywords"  ::: 'PrimaryKey '["id"]]
type Columns
  = '["id" ::: 'Def :=> 'NotNull 'PGint8, "keyword" ::: 'NoDef :=> 'NotNull 'PGtext]
type Table = 'Table (Constraints :=> KColumns)
type Schema = '["keywords" ::: Table]
type Schemas = '["public" ::: Schema]

newtype Keywords = Keywords {unKeywords ::  [Text]} deriving (GHC.Generic)
instance SOP.Generic Keywords
instance SOP.HasDatatypeInfo Keywords
type instance PG Keywords = 'PGvararray ( 'NotNull 'PGtext)
```

### This is the part I need help with:

I'm trying an aggregation query like this:

```
keywords :: Query_ Schemas () Keywords
keywords =
  select_ ((arrayAgg (All #keyword)) `as` #fromOnly) (from (table #keywords))
```

However, I keep getting an error:

```
* Couldn't match type 'NotNull (PG [Text])
                 with 'Null ('PGvararray ty0)
    arising from a use of `as'
```

From what I understand, `arrayAgg` can produce `NULL` so I need to provide a default of empty array `[]` somehow with `fromNull` from here:
https://hackage.haskell.org/package/squeal-postgresql-0.5.1.0/docs/Squeal-PostgreSQL-Expression-Null.html#v:fromNull

But I don't quite know how to provide that.

#### What about the value type mismatch (`PG [Text]` vs `'PGvararray ty0`)? How to solve that?

Answer (score 1):

For the record, the library's author provided a solution as follows:

```hs
keywords :: Query_ Schemas () (Only (VarArray [Text]))
keywords = select_
  (fromNull (array [] & inferredtype) (arrayAgg (All #keyword)) `as` #fromOnly)
  (from (table #keywords) & groupBy Nil)
```

The key factors here are:

1. Provide a default empty array with `fromNull (array [] & inferredtype) ...`. This way we can avoid using `Maybe` in the return type
2. Provide grouping with `groupBy Nil`
3. Choose either `Distinct` or `All` rows in `arrayAgg`
4. Finally, the return type should be `VarArray x`